# Getting solid edge style to win over dashed when using concentrate=true

Tags: graphviz

I am using `concentrate=true` to make nodes with large number of outgoing edges look better. However, when edges with different styles (`solid` and `dashed`) share paths, `dashed` style is often used for the combined edge. Is there any way to make dot render these combined edges as `solid`?